# Why am I getting HTML response from jquery ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I am trying to use jQuery UI autocomplete in my Laravel project to show some suggestions as the user is typing in. Here is the script triggered when the user types in:

```
$(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/autocomplete',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            term : request.term,
            field : $(this.element).prop("id")
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            response(data);
        },
        error: function(result, status, error) {
            console.log(result);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
},
min_length: 0, });
```

Here is my route in web.php

```
Route::get('/autocomplete', 'SitesController@autocomplete');
```

And finally my controller which retrieves results from the database.

```
public function autocomplete(Request $request) {
    $term = \Request::get('term');
    $field = \Request::get('field');
    $sites = Site::where($field, 'ILIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
    ->distinct()
    ->get([$field]);

    $data = [];
    foreach($sites as $key => $site) {
        $data[] = $site->$field;
    }

    return \Response::json($data);
}
```

This is currently not working, but when I directly add the above code to my route files, it does work well.

```
Route::get('/autocomplete', function()
{
    $term = \Request::get('term');
    $field = \Request::get('field');
    $sites = Site::where($field, 'ILIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
    ->distinct()
    ->get([$field]);

    $data = [];
    foreach($sites as $key => $site) {
        $data[] = $site->$field;
    }

    return \Response::json($data);
});
```

My script is returning a HTML response, and here is the error I get from the console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at ajaxConvert (VM258 app.js:18060)
    at done (VM258 app.js:18530)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (VM258 app.js:18832)
```

I can't see why my script is not returning JSON but HTML, while it does when I put my script in the web.php file.

Comment: Check the Network tab in your Developer Console, and look at the response tab of the request to find out exactly what it's returning. It may be throwing an error instead of returning the json.

Comment: You’re most likely throwing an error in your controller or trying to access it. Since the inline code works I’d start by checking that original route is accessing the controller class correctly, I bet it’s missing a namespace or the path is wrong

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by aynber, looking closely at the returned HTML page, I realized it was an error page that I throw thanks to a middleware, when someone is trying to access a page without having the rights. And my controller was of course checking for this middleware first. I made an exception for the autocomplete function and now everything is working fine, though I feel I'm not handling my middlewares the good way...

Answer (score 0):

in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file you can do something like this

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($request->wantsJson()) {
        $response = ... // put your response data here
        return response()->json($response);
    }
    ...
}
```